# SAS include code into data step

Tags: sas, include, datastep

I have dynamically create a myfile.sas with following content:

```
and a = 0
and b = 0
```

Now I want to include this file into a data step:

```
data y;
   set x;

   if 1=1 
      %include incl("myfile.sas")
   then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

The result should be:

```
data y;
   set x;

   if 1=1 
      and a=0
      and b=0
   then myvar=0
   else myvar=1;
run;
```

However I get the following error:

```
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Is this possible to include the file into the if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, that doesn't work. You can use `%include` within a `data` or `proc` step to add some lines to it but not within an incomplete statement.

Had your `myfile.sas` looked like this:

```
if 1=1
and a = 0
and b = 0
```

you could have written

```
data y;
   set x;
   %include "myfile.sas";;
   then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

Couldn't you have these lines in a macro instead of a file?

```
%macro mymacro;
  and a=0
  and b=0
%mend;

data y;
   set x;
   if 1=1 
      %mymacro
   then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

If that `myfile.sas` *has* to stay as is, you could work around it in this rather convoluted (but still generic) way:

```
filename myfile temp;

data _null_;
file myfile2;
infile 'myfile.sas' eof=end;
input;
if _n_=1 then put '%macro mymacro;';
put _infile_;
return;
end:
  put '%mend;';
run;
%include myfile;

data y;
   set x;
   if 1=1 
      %mymacro
   then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%INCLUDE` needs to be at statement boundary. You could put the `IF 1=1` into the same file or into another file. Make sure to include semi-colon to end the `%INCLUDE` command, but don't include a semi-colon in the contents of of the file.

```
data y;
   set x;
%include incl("if1file.sas","myfile.sas") ;
   then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

A better solution might be to put the code into a macro variable (if less than 64K bytes).

```
%let condition=
and a = 0
and b = 0
;

data y;
   set x;
   if 1=1 &condition then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

If it is longer than 64K bytes then define it as a macro instead.

```
%macro condition;
and a = 0
and b = 0
%mend;

data y;
   set x;
   if 1=1 %condition then selektion=0;
   else selektion=1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to SAS documentation:

> %INCLUDE Statement
>
> Brings a SAS programming statement, data lines, or both, into a current SAS program.

The injection you are attempting is not a complete statement, so it fails.  A more specific description of the action you are describing would be %INLINE.  However, there is no such SAS statement.

Let's call a program that outputs code a 'codegener' and the output it produces the 'codegen'

In the context of your use the codegen is specific to a single statement.  This highly suggests the codegener should be placing the codegen in a macro variable (for ease of later use) instead of a file.

Suppose the codegener uses data about statement construction:

```
DATA statements_meta;
  length varname $32 operator $10 value $200;
  input varname operator value;
  datalines;
a = 0
b = 0
run;
```

and the codegener is a DATA step

```
DATA _null_;
  file "myfile.snippet";
  ... looping logic over data for statement construction ...
    put " and " varname " = 0 "
  ...
run;
```

Change the codegener to be more like the following:

```
DATA _null_;
  length snippet $32000;
  snippet = "";
  ... looping logic over data for statement construction ...
    snippet = catx (" ", snippet, "and", varname, comparisonOperator, comparisonValue);
  ... end loop
  call symput('snippet', trim(snippet));
  stop;
run;
...
DATA ...
  if 1=1 &snippet then ... else ...
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

As prior comments stated %include cannot be used inside other SAS statements. That is because %include in NOT a SAS macro, but rather SAS **global statement**. Global statements may only be used between other SAS statement, or as the very first and last statement in a SAS program.

While one cannot use %include for the stated purpose, I wrote a SAS macro function, called **%embed()** that can do just that. You can find %embed macro function definition and usage examples in my blog [Embedding any code anywhere into SAS programs](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2023/05/30/embedding-any-code-anywhere-into-sas-programs/).